# How can I read system mail?

Tags: system, mail

Which packages need to be installed in order for system mail to be generated from for example a nightly rkhunter scan run by cron?

Comment: And, is there anything included by default or must I install a package? I notice that `/usr/bin/mail` is not installed by default.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2261/how-are-administrators-supposed-to-read-roots-mail

Answer (score 14):

I use `mutt` (`sudo apt-get install mutt`) to read it from the command line on my local machine.

You can also forward the mail onto a "real" email address. I have three servers that all do their system error reporting to the root mailbox. I forward these all to my GMail account by editing `/etc/aliases` and adding:

```
webuser: root
root: oli@my-email-domain.com
```

Obviously you'll have a different setup but if you just want your user's email, stick your username in there with your real email address.

Comment: What does the `webuser: root` part do?

Comment: I run my websites under a non-root user (for security). That bit forwards email from the webuser account to root. It just saves me typing out my email address twice.

Comment: +1 for aliases. I make liberal use of them when I setup a server (and to a lesser extent on my desktops). For my servers, I have things like webmaster, postmaster, root, etc. go to mailing lists (really more aliases) so that multiple people easily get the notices.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local email account in Evolution. If the system mails are forwarded to your user you will be also notified about it.