# How can I read system mail on my admin account?

Tags: 10.04, command-line, email

On a new server running lucid, I get "you have new mail" in my admin account. However, I don't have a `mail` command available to read it. Do I need to install it manually (or mutt, etc.), or is a mail client included somewhere in the base install?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are administrators supposed to read root's mail?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2261/how-are-administrators-supposed-to-read-roots-mail)

Comment: I personally just `sudo less +G /var/mail/mail`. `+G` go directly to the end of the file, like `-e` on `journalctl`.

Answer (score 6):

Installing `bsd-mailx` should give you a minimal mail reader command `mail`.  You can rad the mail file with `less` if you wish. You mail will be a file in `/var/mail`.

Setting up your mail server for no local delivery and creating an off-host alias for `root` should get you mail to a central location.  Generally, you will want to use a `Smarthost` for delivery.