# how to set-up (very) simple sendmail

Tags: email, sendmail

I've been trying to get command line sendmail to work, but no success. I need this to output my anacron error *somewhere*.

I've installed the sendmail package. Configured /etc/aliases with:

```
root: me@gmail.com
```

But whenever I'm trying to send an email to *any* address (root, me@gmail.com) the sendmail log keeps telling me its relayed to 'localhost' and sent. Never to be found again. Some files get made in /var/mail/mqueue.

Log output:

```
root@tok:/var/mail# sendmail me@gmail.com test37

Feb 27 13:35:40 tok sendmail[23616]: r1RCZanW023616: from=tys, size=7, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201302271235.r1RCZanW023616@tok.mydomain.nl>, relay=root@localhost
Feb 27 13:35:40 tok sm-mta[23617]: r1RCZe41023617: from=<tys@tok.mydomain.nl>, size=289, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201302271235.r1RCZanW023616@tok.mydomain.nl>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Feb 27 13:35:40 tok sendmail[23616]: r1RCZanW023616: to=me@gmail.com, ctladdr=tys (1000/1000), delay=00:00:04, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30007, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (r1RCZe41023617 Message accepted for delivery)
```

Why does it decide that me@gmail.com should be delivered to localhost and does it never try to actually connect to gmail.com?

How should I configure this? I rather don't have any mailserver running at all. I just want the `sendmail` command to work and to forward my local root mails to mail address.
Can't sendmail just lookup the MX record for the rcpt domain on itself and just deliver it there?

I've also tried putting the alias in /root/.forward, tried forwarding to local file. All without success. I've ran `newaliases` after editing /etc/aliases. I've tried restarting init.d/sendmail.

Comment: My answer [for this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/192572/how-read-local-email-in-thunderbird/199453#199453) might be helpful, as this is how I set up local mail (although for different programs).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you mail is queued.  Just try `mailq` and then `sendmail -q` or `sendmail -q -v`.

Possible is also, that email is being held because of unknown host. You need to have set `localhost` and your `hostname` in `/etc/hosts`

You normally don't need to use `sendmail` from command line to send emails, because it's not very convenient. You should use `mailx` or `mutt`

With `mailx`

```
echo you message  | mail -s subject user@host
```