# Local mail in Thunderbird in /var/mail/username

Tags: 14.04, thunderbird, mail, localhost

I'm trying to configure Thunderbird to read local mail, as described in the answer in similar question:
[How do I read local email in thunderbird?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192572/how-read-local-email-in-thunderbird)

However my mail is stored in `/var/mail/username` file. Thunberbird is looking for mail in `/var/spool/mail/` and I get errors that this directory can not be read.

How to configure Thunberbird to read mail from `/var/mail/username`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ls -l /var/spool/mail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Feb 14  2012 /var/spool/mail -> ../mail
```

As displayed, my `/var/spool/mail` is just a symlink back to `/var/mail`. I didn't create that but if you don't have it, and it's causing you significant grief in Thunderbird, I wouldn't hesitate to add a link:

```
sudo ln -s '../mail' /var/spool/mail
```

---

And now I read [the original answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/199453/449), it does suggest to use `/var/mail/username` and shows a screenshot of how to specify it (in the **Server Settings** tab).

---

If you're getting read errors and `/var/spool/mail` exists check:

- `file /var/spool/mail` to make sure it's the right thing
- `stat /var/mail/$USER` is it accessibly by your current user? Is it owned by the right person? Have you copied this from a filesystem with different UID/GIDs? If in doubt, reset the permissions back to the correct ones:

  ```
  sudo chown $USER:mail /var/mail/$USER
  chmod 0600 /var/mail/$USER
  ```

Comment: Changing the storage dir as in the original answer does not change anything, still the same error message. Also my `/var/spool/mail/` dir exists, and contains `/var/spool/mail/username` file.

Comment: I've added an if-all-else-fails section.