# How to require new users to provide their email address when creating their accounts?

Tags: server, email, adduser

I want to create user accounts to new users on our shared computer, but I found the user profile doesn't have the email address field. Can I add the email address field and require new users to fill it out?

More details: I used

```
sudo adduser <username>
```

to create new accounts to new users. Then it asked for the Full Name, Phone, Home-Phone and Other fields for their user profiles. No field called email. I'd like to use the email field in the future to automatically email all users for computer updates and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe the *"other"* field can be used for that - see [GECOS field: Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field#Format)

Comment: Usually the user account is an email address as well (`<username>@<hostanme>`), and you set up an MTA to deliver emails locally, which they can then forward or read locally as they wish. https://askubuntu.com/questions/192572/how-do-i-read-local-email-in-thunderbird

Comment: @muru Is that possible to send emails to their remote email address? If there is not such a way, I'll use *Other* as the email address field for now, as steeldriver said.

Comment: @XiaodongQi you use aliases: https://askubuntu.com/a/2268/158442

Comment: @muru With that, possibly I can write a script to declare "other" as the aliases of usernames for all users and automate the emailing jobs. Thanks.