# Simplest MTA mail setup for a desktop to receive (ana)cron emails

Tags: email, cron, mail, mta

Ubuntu (12.04 LTS) doesn't seem to install any sort of mailer by default.

Everybody seems to recommend installing Postfix. I am familiar with Postfix, which I use on several "real" servers.

But it feels wrong to install a heavy-duty fully featured mail server on a desktop, just so that (ana)cron emails have somewhere to go. There must be a more light-weight solution for such a trivial local-only task .

Which is the simplest mailer to install on my notebook, just so that system emails like cron errors are saved somewhere (just written to /var/mail/username would be sufficient).

Comment: Give it a read to this http://askubuntu.com/q/2261/169736, in summary, there are several.

Comment: Thanks. I had read that, but it recommends postfix. Or nullmailer which relays mail to another server, which I don't need. Local delivery into a Maildir or mbox file is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

The same question appeared on Unix.SE a while back:

- [Minimal MTA that delivers mail locally (for cron)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82093/8250)

MTAs such as Postfix and Exim have a much broader scope. Since I could not really find a single program specific for the purpose of "delivering" mail to a single directory, I ended up writing a new program, [femtomail](https://git.lekensteyn.nl/femtomail/).

Have a look at the Unix.SE question for details or read the README in the femtomail repository.

Comment: Thanks for femtomail! I have one bug report - it is necessary to manually create folder for mailing box, it is no done as part of the installation (I used default mailbox path and I installed femtomail on Ubuntu 14.04 as instructed by its readme).

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny Fixed in the README, thanks!