# how to read root e-mails with alpine?

Tags: command-line, email, postfix, hostname, email-client

While I can send and receive e-mails with Amazon as root, I can't seem to do the same on my local system.  Both are `xenial` 16.04, so shouldn't be that different.

On Amazon, as root, I can launch `alpine` to ready system messages.  Even when I gain a root shell on my local system, and change the working directory, `alpine` uses the `.pinerc` config file from `/home/thufir/.pinerc` for reasons beyond me.

How can I configure my local computer to read system e-mails with `alpine` instead of of the `mail` command?  The `mail` command comes from `mailutils` which uses `postfix`; both remote (Amazon) and local systems have different FQDN's registered through www.no-ip.com free service.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2261/how-are-administrators-supposed-to-read-roots-mail?

Comment: maybe.  perhaps if I run postfix config as suggested in one of the answers it will automagically fix itself?  Not sure I'll get at it right now, but will do.  Thanks.